# How to split string of letters two numbers and one number in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a list of values that has the following structure: **word number number** the part of numbers has exactly two numbers and the second has floating values. Here is an example

```
abcd 01 23,456,789 efgh 01 23,456,789
```

This i my current pattern:

```
re.findall("([a-zá-úA-Z]+)([0-9,.][0-9,.])([0-9,.]+)"
```

But it is not working. Just give me []

The **result** will be:

```
[ abcd 01 23,456,789, 
efgh 01 23,456,789 ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: "the first number has exactly two numbers": Please explain how this is possible.

Comment: Your re doesn't account for the space between things.

Comment: @ScottHunter edited. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following solution:

```py
import re

data = 'abcd 01 23,456,789 efgh 01 23,456,789'
pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zá-úA-z]+\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9,]+')
matches = re.findall(pattern, data)
```

Comment: This assumes the sizes of things not stated in problem.

Comment: "The first number has exactly two numbers (...)" @ScottHunter

Answer (score 2):

As **@Scott Hunter** mentioned in comments, you forgot the **space**. Just adding them do the job.

The following regex do not assume a fix length, it's a bit more robust.

```
import re

data = "abcd 01 23,456,789 efgh 01 23,456,789"

output = re.findall("([a-zá-úA-Z]+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+[,]\d+[,]\d+)", data)

print(output)
# [('abcd', '01', '23,456,789'), ('efgh', '01', '23,456,789')]
```